# How do I use a period in a Quicksilver object (search for a file with a period)?

Tags: macos, quicksilver

How do I use a period in a Quicksilver object to do things like search for a file with a period? By default pressing period anywhere in an object causes Quicksilver to switch to text mode.

Optimally I would like period to only enter text mode when its at the start of the object. Or perhaps there is a wildcard I can use (* doesn't seem to work and . obviously doesn't :). Or perhaps there is an escape sequence for period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way!  Hold down <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> while pressing <kbd>.</kbd>, so <kbd>⌃⌥.</kbd> – that should do it.

Theoretically this is a shortcoming of Quicksilver, but not really: if there is a period in the middle of the file there shouldn't be any need to actually type it.  If your file is "Apples.Are.Good.jpg" just typing "applesaregood" or "apples" or "app" is probably enough to find it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](http://juanlarios.blogspot.de/2007/11/use-quicksilver-to-access-hidden-files.html) is helpful?

1. Access QuickSilver. Start entering 'Mac' and one of the top options is 'Macintosh HD'
2. Select 'Macintosh HD' but before opening it up with the action 'Open', enter 'Alt - /'. This will give you access to all the hidden files in that folder.
3. By entering '?' you can move up a level.

Comment: It doesn't help in my particular case, but I agree its probably helpful for others who are trying to get to dot files and don't know this trick.